# Unexpected EZForm multi radio form field behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms

I've tried to edit existed model with EZFrom component

code cut from lib demo app

```
EZFormMultiRadioFormField *likesField = [[EZFormMultiRadioFormField alloc] initWithKey:EZFDRegistrationFormLikesKey];
likesField.choices = @{
@"everything" : @"Everything",
@"pizza" : @"Pizza",
@"pasta" : @"Pasta",
@"bacon" : @"Bacon",
@"salad" : @"Salad",
@"cheese" : @"Cheese",
@"tacos" : @"Tacos"
};

NSArray * predefinedFieldValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pizza", @"tacos", nil];
[likesField setFieldValue:predefinedFieldValues];
```

I expected to see list with checked "pizza" and "tacos" items, but nothing happened
What wrong with my expectations? In other words: how to show multi radio form with predefined selected items? e.g. existed object edit form solution

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Solution has been found by myself :-)

Look. If you want to select more than one value, you should call setValue several times.
e.g.

```
[likesField setFieldValue:@"pizza"];
[likesField setFieldValue:@"tacos"];
```